# Can't import CSS module styles - Cannot find module '**.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations (Gatsby App)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, css-modules

I created a Gatsby app and followed every step after running `gatsby new`. I have not made any custom changes. When I try to import styles from a CSS Module I get the following error `Cannot find module '[your-filename].module.css' or its corresponding type declarations`. Yes, I have the path mapped properly. I've done endless Googling and add this point am at a loss.

Gatsby claims CSS modules are supported out of the box so I have no idea what I've done wrong considering I have followed their steps exactly without making any changes. Please help.

I've tried Googling this problem. It does seem like a couple people have ran into similar issue but the solutions provided in those posts didn't work and usually seemed overly complicated for something that is supposed to work OUT OF THE BOX.